# How do property binding works with directives in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding, angular2-directives, property-binding

So I understand how basic property binding works in angular for elements like input, but I came across some code that was using node module `ng-drag-drop` which comes with a set of its own custom directives. In html of a component there is a div element that uses one of the directives called `droppable` and property binding `[dragOverClass]="'drag-target-border-green'"` but DIV elements have no property like `dragOverClass`. So where does it come from? The directive? I was checking angular docs for data binding and it says nothing about this, just basic property binding chapter with input value examples. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is part of the directive a custom input.

Comment: So is that still property binding? And can you elaborate a little bit more about directive custom input? If I didn't define directive name on DIV element, this binding would not be working, right?

Comment: It is from the directive. see this [link](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#binding-to-an-input-property)

Comment: No it wouldn't work. It's a bit complicated to explain as i'm not to experienced as i would like to be with directives.

Comment: The custom inputs are used by the directive to morph itself based on the input given. Kind of like when you set a width on an element. "width" in that case is a input which is then used to determine the width of the element in question. Directives allow for customization of elements.

Comment: Okay guys, so you say it's @Input binding for directives. I read the link about it on angular docs page. All clear. The only problem is that my `ng-drag-drop` module directives don't import and use @input decorator anywhere. How then does it work without it? It's just a bunch  of properties like this `dragOverClass: string;` inside draggable.directive.d.ts file.